# Is there any way to rename labels in Darkflow pretrained dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, yolo, darkflow

I encountered a problem when running on a video. When it detects a street lamp, it shows a bird. Is there anyway to rename the label or remove the label?

I have tried to edit the misc.py but it is not working. Below is the screenshot of the detected image.
[image]

```
labels20 = ["aeroplane", "bicycle", "lamp", "boat", "bottle",
    "bus", "car", "cat", "chair", "cow", "diningtable", "dog",
    "horse", "motorbike", "person", "pottedplant", "sheep", "sofa",
     "train", "tvmonitor"]
```

I am trying to get rid of the label or if I can, change the labels name.

Comment: The labels you provide `labels20` doesn't have bird at all. Where does your program get it from?!

Comment: No I change the bird to lamp

Comment: Where is this line `labels20 = ["aeroplane", "bicycle", "lamp", "boat", "bottle",
    "bus", "car", "cat", "chair", "cow", "diningtable", "dog",
    "horse", "motorbike", "person", "pottedplant", "sheep", "sofa",
     "train", "tvmonitor"]` from? Is it inside a file or code?

Comment: It's inside a code. File name is misc.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change **bird** to **lamp** inside a file with extension **.names**, not inside the code.

Comment: I changed it in coco.names file.